# Where is the firefox 40.0.3 "Log Request and Response Bodies" check box?

Tags: firefox

To view the req/res body, it says that I have to enable "Log Request and Response Bodies"

Where's it though? (firefox 40.0.3). If I click a get response from network tab, it shows the headers but nowhere is there place to enable Log req/res bodies".

I am trying to view json data coming in.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the Console. Example:

> [image: example]